# R sub replacing part of identified string

Tags: r, regex

Hi I have a large dataframe of addresses which I need to clean. One of the problems is where I wish to replace a number and suffix with an unwanted whitespace as follows

```
original <- c("73 A Acacia Avenue","656 B East Street", " FLAT 1 D High Road", "66B West Street")
corrected <- c("73A Acacia Avenue","656B East Street", " FLAT 1D High Road")
```

I can identify and isolate what I wish to change using grep and regexpr, but am not sure how to remove the offending space and replace the correction in the original dataframe

```
reg <- "([0-9]+ [A-Z] )"
grep(reg, original, value = T, perl =T) # finds match
grep(reg, original, perl =T) # finds match row
regexpr(reg,match) # finds position
findstr <- regmatches(match,r) # show relevant string
```

So my final stage is to remove the whitespace and apply the correction.
Any help appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `gsub` with your (a bit modified) regex and `\1\2` replacement:

```
original <- c("73 A Acacia Avenue","656 B East Street", " FLAT 1 D High Road", "66B West Street")
reg <- "([0-9]+)\\s([A-Z]\\s+)"
gsub(reg, "\\1\\2", original)
## => [1] "73A Acacia Avenue" "656B East Street" " FLAT 1D High Road" [4] "66B West Street"
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/aI1yOW).

**Details**:

- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1 matching one or more digits
- `\\s` - a whitespace
- `([A-Z]\\s+)` - Group 2 matching an uppercase ASCII letter and then 1 or more whitespaces.

The replacement is `\1\2` where `\1` is the value of the first group and `\2` references the value in the second group.